# DRF documentation module gets correct shema, but fails with HTML renderer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I setup DRF documetation with `include_docs_urls`, HTML page will render only modules, explicitly indicated in project's `urls.py`.
But all modules, added to `urlpatterns` with `django.conf.urls.include` function, HTML renderer will ignore it. But coreapi-cli gets right schema.

If code is:

```
api_patterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-refresh/$', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-verify/$', verify_jwt_token),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HTMLReport.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^vending/', include('vending.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/$', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-tools/$', include(api_patterns)),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='TMS API', description='Terminal Management System API', public=True))
]
```

HTML would ignore docs for `vending.urls`, and `api_patterns`.

But if code is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HTMLReport.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^vending/', include('vending.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/$', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-refresh/$', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-verify/$', verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='TMS API', description='Terminal Management System API', public=True))
]
```

Only `vending.urls` are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
url(r'^api-tools/$', include(api_patterns)),
```

Try to use concatenation of url_patterns:

```
urlpatterns + api_patterns
```

and change the position of

```
url(r'^vending/', include('vending.urls')),
```

to this way:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HTMLReport.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/$', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='TMS API', description='Terminal Management System API', public=True))
    url(r'^vending/', include('vending.urls')),
]
urlpatterns + api_patterns
```

If still `vending.urls` is ignored then try to use namespace.